# mongoose 'or' and 'like' operators node.js

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, mongodb

I wan to implement search for my page. So from frontEnd I got search value from user's input, and I need search at my db with 3 rows limit.
So I need sql query like that:
SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS p WHERE p.title like '%user_value%' or p.sku like '%user_value%'

I try to do it like that:

```
router.get('/search', function(req, res, next) {
    var value = req.query.val;
    var query = Product.find({"title":  new RegExp('/' + value+'/')}).limit(3);

    query.exec(function(err, products) {
        if (!err) {
            // Method to construct the json result set
            var result =  JSON.stringify(products);
            log.info(products);

            res.send(result, {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }, 200);
        } else {
            res.send(JSON.stringify(err), {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }, 404);
        }
    });
```

But I always got empty results. Its seems to me that RegExp path invalid.

**UPDATE1:**
'like' operator fixed like that:

```
Product.find({"title": new RegExp(".*" + value + ".*")}).limit(3);
```

But `"or p.sku like '%user_value%'"` problem still take a place

Comment: are you trying to include variable `value`in RegExp? Then `var query = Product.find({"title":  new RegExp(value)}).limit(3);`

Comment: mm,just value, but I need like %value%?

Comment: try `var query = Product.find({"title": new RegExp(".*" + value + ".*")}).limit(3);`

Comment: thx, this works , but How I can add case ignore? , where should I put 'i' attr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass modifiers as second parameter in `RegExp` constructor.

```
var query = Product.find({"title": new RegExp(".*" + value.replace(/(\W)/g, "\\$1") + ".*", "i")}).limit(3);
```

**Example:**

```
> var value = 'SNR-SFP+W73-60'
> console.log(new RegExp(".*" + value.replace(/(\W)/g, "\\$1") + ".*", "i"))
/.*SNR\-SFP\+W73\-60.*/i
```

Comment: I have some troubles , then value variable has text like that 'SNR-SFP+W73-60' its find nothing, but must

Comment: Works! very appreciate

Answer (score 0):

In your RegExp object you should do this:

```
new RegExp(value)
```

instead of this:

```
new RegExp('/' + value + '/')
```

Refer this link:
[RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)